# Python. How to optimize search functions

Tags: python, list, optimization

There any way to optimize these two functions ?

first function:

```
def searchList(list_, element):
    for i in range (0,len(list_)):
        if(list_[i] == element):
            return True      
    return False
```

second function:

```
return_list=[]
for x in list_search:
    if searchList(list_users,x)==False:
        return_list.append(x)
```

Comment: Before asking for a faster way to do something, you should first explain what you are trying to do!

Comment: Convert `list_users` to a  `set` and check for item simply using the `in` operator.

Comment: Optimize for what? Readability? Speed? Memory usage? Either way, since your question is about working code, it's better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes:

```
return_list = [x for x in list_search if x not in list_users]
```

The first function basically checks for membership, in which case you could use the [`in` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in). The second function can be reduced to a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter out elements from `list_search` list based on your condition.

Comment: `in` is O(n) for list. If you wanted to get really crazy you can write a binary search (if applicable) which would reduce this to logn!

Answer (score 4):

For first function

```
def searchList(list, element):
   return element in list
```

You can make it in 1 line

```
searchList = lambda x,y: y in x
```

For 2nd, use a list comp like shown in the other answer

Comment: Good point ! first time i seen this question and vote the first answer! but i miss this elegant answer!

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** I assumed `list_search` has no duplicate elements. Otherwise, use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28570994/793428).

What you want is exactly the set [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Complements) of `list_users` in `list_search`.

As an alternative approach, you can use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to get the difference between two lists and I think it should be much more performant than the naive look up which takes `0(n^2)`.

```
>>> list_search = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list_users = [4, 5, 1, 6]
>>> print set(list_search).difference(list_users)
>>> {2, 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing with your two functions is building the complement as ozgur pointed out.
Using sets is the most easy thing here

```
>>> set([2,2,2,3,3,4])- set([1,2,2,4,5])
set([3])
```

your `list_search` would be the first list and your `list_users` the second list.
The only difference is that your new user is only once in the result no matter how often it is in the `list_search`