# How to subtract two iterables in python

Tags: python, list, subtraction

There are two lists A and B. I want to get all the elements in A but not in B. Any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a list comprehension to do this for you.

```
filtered = [i for i in A if i not in B]
```

If the lists are both large, you might want to consider creating a `set` from `B` for faster membership lookup

```
setB = set(B)
filtered = [i for i in A if i not in setB]
```

This solution maintains the order of `A` and any duplicates that exist in `A`.

Comment: this might be simple, how about the complexity?

Comment: @Avoen If you convert `B` to a `set`, this is `O(N)` time complexity.

Answer (score 4):

i always like to use sets for this:

```
set(A) - set(B)
```

edit: except if A has duplicates or you care about order, then use @Cyber's answer

Comment: This works well as long as order and count of items don't matter.

Answer (score -2):

sets are great for this purpose

```
set(A) - set(B)
```

eg

```
>>> set([2,2,2,3,3,4])- set([1,2,2,4,5])
set([3])
```

btw. this looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569724/how-to-optimize-these-two-functions-in-python/28570360#28570360)